# How to reference variables that haven't been initialized yet?

Tags: c#, game-engine

Say I have this setup:

```
public class Game
{
    public static World World;
    public static Camera Camera;
    public static Player Player;

    public Game()
    {
        World = new World();
        Camera = new Camera();
        Player = new Player();
    }
}
```

In the camera constructor I use the world object to position the camera, however I also need to access the camera in the world constructor. I cant just use `Main.Camera` because it hasn't been initialized yet. How do I solve this issue? Is there a programming pattern that I can use to avoid this circular dependency problem?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, here, but you're defining a variable with exactly the same name as the class?... `public static World World;` - there's no distinction, such as `public static World world;` or `public static World _world;`...

Comment: nit: the problem is not one of referencing the variables - nor is it that they haven't been initialized yet (at least, in the definite assignment sense) - you already *can* reference those fields - and they are initialized as `null`; the problem is rather the "circular dependency" bit; in which case, you'll have to pick one to initialize *without* the circle, and fix it up afterwards; i.e. `a = new A(); b = new B(a); a.B = b;`; as a side note: have `static` fields that are initialized in an *instance* constructor sounds like a terrible idea; are you sure you didn't mean `readonly` instead?

Comment: @Paul that's entirely valid i.e. not a problem - the compiler can cope with that; the only caveat is that you might *in some cases* need to use the fully qualified name to get at static members of those types in the future, i.e. `global::Some.Namespace.Player.SomeStaticMethod()` instead of `Player.SomeStaticMethod()` (which might try to resolve as an instance method) - although even *that* usually resolves just fine, with the compiler and even syntax-highlighting doing the right thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the initialization order

```cs
public class Game
{
    public static World World;
    public static Camera Camera;
    public static Player Player;

    public Game()
    {
        Camera = new Camera();
        World = new World(Camera);
        Player = new Player();
    }
}
```

If there's a mutual dependence (both depend on each other), you have a problem in your design (circular dependency anti-pattern). You'll probably need to rethink your design. Try not to make a "global object" that holds the state of everything. That's also a design anti-pattern. You need to give details (in a separate question) in order for specific tips.

Comment: While this works, I'm more interested in solving the anti-pattern you mentioned instead of working around it.

Comment: @gamer1 in that case you should give more details on the design. What do the classes represent, how are they connected, etc. Better to do that in a separate question, as changing this one will invalidate the answer and comments.